# About upgrading windows 8 to 8.1

Tags: windows

I was upgrading windows but now it stuck at "Windows is getting your windows 8.1 update ready. You will automatically prompted to install windows 8.1 soon. "

I've tried to uninstall and install KB2871389 manually, cleared Store caches, so basically everything I found on google.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suH7Z.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can grab a Win8.1 DVD to install. If your CD-KEY is valid, it doesn't matter which media are you using to upgrade.